# Optimizing a program and calculating % of total execution time improved

Tags: performance, optimization, timing

So I was told to ask this on here instead of StackExchage:

If I have a program P, which runs on a 2GHz machine M in 30seconds and is optimized by replacing all instances of 'raise to the power 4' with 3 instructions of multiplying x by. This optimized program will be P'. The CPI of multiplication is 2 and CPI of power is 12. If there are 10^9 such operations optimized, what is the percent of total execution time improved?

Here is what I've deduced so far.
For P, we have:

```
        time (30s)
        CPI: 12
        Frequency (2GHz)
```

For P', we have:

```
            CPI (6) [2*3]
            Frequency (2GHz)
```

So I need to figure our how to calculate the time of P' in order to compare the times. But I have no idea how to achieve this. Could someone please help me out?

Comment: Frequency is the total count of available clocks per second; you can compute how much clocks there are in 30 seconds; First program has 10^9 operations of "raise to power 4" each is executed in 12 clocks (12 CPI) - so you can compute their part of execution time from total clock count in 30 seconds and get the time of not-optimized part of program.

Comment: @osgx You lost me at computing their part of execution time from total clock count in 30 seconds. Could you please go a bit more in depth about how I can do this?

Comment: You program need to compute 10^9 "raise to 4 power" instructions with 12CPI and some X instructions with mean Y CPI. You need 10^9 * 12 cycles for raising and X*Y instructions for other instructions. And your CPU has 2 GHz (2 * 10^9 cycles every second). Total program P running time is 30 sec and equal to (10^9 * 12  + X*Y ) / 2 000 000 000. You can get "X*Y" part from such formula; then you change your raising instruction into 3 mul instructions and recompute P' running time with "X*Y" plus new mul instuction count and CPI.

Comment: Do I need to calculate out X and Y separately or can I treat them as a single unknown since it seems like their individual values are irrelevant for what I need to solve? Also, I followed your explanation (and treated X and Y as a single unknown) and got the new time to equal 27 seconds. Does that sound about right? I would think the improvement would be a bit greater since we're going from 12CPI to 6CPI.

Comment: I don't know right answer, this looks like your hometask, not my. If the total time of "raise to 4 power" instructions was low in original program, improvement may be small. Ok, if you have your own answer, I'll try too: P: 30*2=12+XY, XY=48 (*10^9) ticks. P' T=(XY+6)/2=(48+6)/2 = 27sec. XY part was 80%, and raise part was 20% of P time; improve 20% twofold and get 80%+10% of 30 seconds, 27 looks good. What we can learn: **don't optimize part of program which has low percent of running time**, even if you will half its time it is still small part.. PS: I think you can post your solution as ans

Comment: Wouldn't the improvement be 10% since 27/30 = 0.9? Either way, thank you for your help! I'll post the solution if my 10% belief is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Program P, which runs on a 2GHz machine M in 30 seconds and is optimized by replacing all instances of 'raise to the power 4' with 3 instructions of multiplying x by. This optimized program will be P'. The CPI of multiplication is 2 and CPI of power is 12. If there are 10^9 such operations optimized,

From this information we can compute time needed to execute all POWER4 ("raise to the power 4) instructions, we have total count of such instructions (all POWER4 was replaced, count is 10^9 or 1 G). Every POWER4 instruction needs 12 clock cycles (CPI = clock per instruction), so all POWER4 were executed in 1G * 12 = 12G cycles.

2GHz machine has 2G cycles per second, and there are 30 seconds of execution. Total P program execution is 2G*30 = 60 G cycles (60 * 10^9). We can conclude that P program has some other instructions. We don't know what instructions, how many executions they have and there is no information about their mean CPI. But we know that time needed to execute other instructions is 60 G - 12 G  = 48 G (total program running time minus POWER4 running time - true for simple processors). There is some X executed instructions with Y mean CPI, so X*Y = 48 G.

So, total cycles executed for the program P is

Freq * seconds = POWER4_count * POWER4_CPI + OTHER_count * OTHER_mean_CPI

2G * 30 = 1G * 12 + X*Y

Or total running time for P:

30s = (1G * 12 + X*Y) / 2GHz

> what is the percent of total execution time improved?

After replacing 1G POWER4 operations with 3 times more MUL instructions (multiply by) we have 3G MUL operations, and cycles needed for them is now CPI * count, where MUL CPI is 2:  2*3G = 6G cycles. X*Y part of P' was unchanged, and we can solve the problem.

P' time in seconds = ( MUL_count * MUL_CPI + OTHER_count * OTHER_mean_CPI ) / Frequency

P' time = (3G*2 + X*Y) / 2GHz

Improvement is not so big as can be excepted, because POWER4 instructions in P takes only some part of running time: 12G/60G; and optimization converted 12G to 6G, without changing remaining 48 G cycles part. By halving only some part of time we get not half of time.